# Hash algorithm for string of characters using XOR and bit shift

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, xor, bit-shift

I was given this algorithm to write a hash function:

> BEGIN Hash (string)
>   UNSIGNED INTEGER key = 0;
>   FOR_EACH character IN string
>   key = ((key << 5) + key) ^ character;
>   END FOR_EACH
>   RETURN key;
>   END Hash

The `<<`operator refers to shift bits to the left. The `^` refers to the XOR operation and the character refers to the ASCII value of the character. Seems pretty straightforward.

Below is my code

```
unsigned int key = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    key = ((key<<5) + key) ^ (int)data[i];
}
return key;
```

However, I keep getting ridiculous positive and negative huge numbers when i should actually get a hash value from 0 - `n`. `n` is a value set by the user beforehand. I'm not sure where things went wrong but I'm thinking it could be the `XOR` operation.

Any suggestions or opinions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, you should not have to cast the character to an `int`, C++ automatically promotes `char` to `int` in arithmetic expressions. Secondly, you might want to split up the big expression into its sub-expressions, and perform them separately, then step through the code, line by line, in a debugger to see what really happens and what all values of the sub-expressions are.

Comment: And you say you get *negative* values? From an *unsigned* variable? Maybe you just print it as a signed value? Or assign it to an unsigned variable? Please show us how you check the returned value.

Comment: As an aside, `key` is unsigned, so why are you explicitly casting your data to a _signed_ int?

Comment: Here's my suggestion: don't ever use hashing for anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The output of this code is a 32-bit (or 64-bit or however wide your `unsigned int` is) unsigned integer.  To restrict it to the range from 0 to *n*−1, simply reduce it modulo *n*, using the `%` operator:

```
unsigned int hash = key % n;
```

(It should be obvious that your code, as written, *cannot* return "a hash value from 0 - `n`", since `n` does not appear anywhere in your code.)

In fact, there's a good reason *not* to reduce the hash value modulo *n* too soon: if you ever need to grow your hash, storing the unreduced hash codes of your strings saves you the effort of recalculating them whenever *n* changes.

Finally, a few general notes on your hash function:

- As Joachim Pileborg comments above, the explicit `(int)` cast is unnecessary.  If you want to keep it for clarity, it really should say `(unsigned int)` to match the type of `key`, since that's what the value actually gets converted into.
- For unsigned integer types, `((key<<5) + key)` is equal to `33 * key` (since shifting left by 5 bits is the same as multiplying by 2<sup>5</sup> = 32).  On modern CPUs, using multiplication is almost certainly faster; on old or very low-end processors with slow multiplication, it's likely that any decent compiler will optimize multiplication by a constant into a combination of shifts and adds anyway.  Thus, either way, expressing the operation as a multiplication is IMO preferable.
- You don't want to call `data.length()` on every iteration of the loop.  Call it once before the loop and store the result in a variable.
- Initializing `key` to zero means that your hash value is not affected by any leading zero bytes in the string.  The [original version](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html#djb2) of your hash function, due to Dan Bernstein, uses a (more or less random) initial value of 5381 instead.